# How to install Parallel::ForkManager in Perl?

Tags: perl

I am tiring to run multiple jobs in parallel by using perl script which use Parallel:ForkManager.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl  -w

use Parallel::ForkManager;

my @make_obj = qw(
 mode1_testlist
 mode1_testlist1
 mode1_testlist2
);

my $fm = $pm = Parallel::ForkManager-> new(3);
foreach my $obj (@make_obj) {
  $fm->start and next;
  print("make regression MODE=1 MODELIST=$make_obj");
  $fm->finish();
}
```

but it throws me below error.

> Can't locate Parallel/ForkManager.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/lib64/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8 .) at parallel_run.pl line 3.
> BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at parallel_run.pl line 3.

I have downloaded *Parallel-ForkManager-1.03.tar.gz* but I don't know where to keep it I mean how to install it.

I tried `perl Makefile.PL && make test && make install`:

```
WARNING: META_MERGE is not a known parameter.
WARNING: BUILD_REQUIRES is not a known parameter.
WARNING: LICENSE is not a known parameter.
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
'BUILD_REQUIRES' is not a known MakeMaker parameter name.
'LICENSE' is not a known MakeMaker parameter name.
'META_MERGE' is not a known MakeMaker parameter name.
Writing Makefile for Parallel::ForkManager
cp lib/Parallel/ForkManager.pm blib/lib/Parallel/ForkManager.pm
PERL_DL_NONLAZY=1 /usr/bin/perl "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-e"test_harness(0,'blib/lib', 'blib/arch')" t/*.t
                                                                                            t/00-load.............ok 1/3    (in cleanup) Undefined subroutine 
&File::Path::remove_tree called at /h/altera_dump2/vjain419/regression_flow_bck
/regression_flow/MSS1/hw/verif/top_/00e/tools/Parallel-ForkManager-1.03/blib
/lib/Parallel  /ForkManager.pm line 662.
t/00-load.............ok
t/01-utf8-all.........skipped
    all skipped: Need utf8::all for this test crashing on Windows
    t/02-callback.........Array found where operator expected at t/02-callback.t line
    21,at  end of line
    (Do you need to predeclare explain?)
    syntax error at t/02-callback.t line 21, near "explain @out"
   xecution of t/02-callback.t aborted due to compilation errors.
   # Looks like your test died before it could output anything.
   t/02-callback.........dubious                                                
    Test returned status 255 (wstat 65280, 0xff00)
     DIED. FAILED tests 1-2
    Failed 2/2 tests, 0.00% okay
    t/03-callback-data....Array found where operator expected at t/03-callback-data.t line 13, at end of line
    (Do you need to predeclare explain?)
   syntax error at t/03-callback-data.t line 13, near "explain @out"
   Execution of t/03-callback-data.t aborted due to compilation errors.
    # Looks like your test died before it could output anything.
    t/03-callback-data....dubious                                                
    Test returned status 255 (wstat 65280, 0xff00)
    DIED. FAILED test 1
    Failed 1/1 tests, 0.00% okay
   Failed Test          Stat Wstat Total Fail  Failed  List of Failed
   t/02-callback.t       255 65280     2    4 200.00%  1-2
   t/03-callback-data.t  255 65280     1    2 200.00%  1
   1 test skipped.
   Failed 2/4 test scripts, 50.00% okay. 3/6 subtests failed, 50.00% okay.
   make: *** [test_dynamic] Error 255
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just use

```
cpan Parallel::ForkManager
```

Alternatively, execute the following command after making sure you have its dependencies (POSIX, Storable, File::Spec, File::Temp, File::Path 2.00 and Test::More 0.81_01) installed:

```
tar xvzf Parallel-ForkManager-1.03.tar.gz
cd Parallel-ForkManager-1.03
perl Makefile.PL && make test && make install
```

Comment: i am installing it on remote server. when i use `cpan` command its try to connect with some FTP! my server is not connected to internet!

Comment: i had edited my question.I am not able to get what is wrong when i used your 2nd option for installing

Comment: It requires File::Path 2.00 or higher, even though the version wasn't specified in Makefile.PL. It requires Test::More 0.81_01 even though 0.80 was specified in Makefile.PL.

Comment: i didnt know about `File::Path 2.00` can you please tell me what should i do so i can use fork-manager.!

Comment: i just look over google for `File::Path` and `Test::More` so this is available on [link](http://search.cpan.org/~mschwern/Test-Simple-0.98/lib/Test/More.pm). do i have to install it ?

Comment: just FYI i am not admin of that server. I need to run some jobs in parallel! if there is another way out like some script then please let me know!

Comment: Looked into the dependencies of this 
**http://deps.cpantesters.org/?module=Parallel%3A%3AForkManager;perl=latest**
I think you need not to install all dependent modules as those are core module so it should readily be available with perl.
`perl Makefile.PL && make test && make install` worked fine for me.
What's the log says when you run this commands ?

Comment: @SuvasishSarker i have edited my question by adding Error log which i am getting while running `perl Makefile.PL && make test && make install`

Comment: @SuvasishSarker i am using perl 5.8.8 i checked dependencies on link which you provided please check this [link](http://deps.cpantesters.org/?module=Parallel%3A%3AForkManager&perl=5.8.8&os=Linux) for result!...i think i have to add `TEST:MORE`

Comment: when i tried to install `TEST:MORE` `make install` giving me below warning!`Warning: You do not have permissions to install into /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi at /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/ExtUtils/Install.pm line 114.
Cannot forceunlink /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/Test/Builder.pm: Permission denied at /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/File/Find.pm line 924` 
I think i should have admin access to install this!!

Comment: @SuvasishSarker i install new perl version in my local directory and using it now.!

Comment: Great so you did it finally :)

Comment: @SuvasishSarker yes somehow ;) one more issue. As i have install perl in my local path.! how to change default perl path! i mean when i check `which perl` its shows me `/usr/bin/perl` i want to modify it one where i have install it! I tried to give it in 1st line of my code but when i run that script using `perl script.pl` it take `\usr\bin\perl` as source !

Comment: @vjain419, Put the path to your local `perl` before `/usr/bin` in the `PATH` env var.

Comment: @Suvasish Sarker, He's asking about locating the correct `perl` binary, not about locating libraries. PERL5LIB won't help. `PERL5LIB` would be useful if he had installed the module using the system Perl into a nonstandard dir, but he went an installed Perl itself in a non-standard dir.

Comment: @SuvasishSarker i still didnt get how to do that! how should `PERL5LIB` help me?!

Comment: If you installed modules locally by using `perl Makefile.PL PREFIX=~/perl5 LIB=~/perl5/lib`, you can set env var `PERL5LIB` to `~/perl5/lib`. I didn't mention this since you had already installed Perl, which is actually a way better option than mucking with an very outdated system Perl

Comment: Also, running `cpan .` inside a distro directly will install the dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

Like some of the comments on the accepted answer suggest, there can be a dependency missing.  The following worked for me:

```
% cpan Test::More
% cpan Parallel::ForkManager
```

Comment: `cpan` can install multiple modules with one command line: `cpan Test::More Parallel::ForkManager`.